# React Tailwind - not able to start my app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, tailwind-css

I was trying to use Tailwind css with react project, i followed the exact instructions on Tailwind website  on how to use Tailwind in React but when trying to run `npm run start` it displays :

```
Failed to compile.

EIO: i/o error, read
```

did anyone ever faced this, ad please how to solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried updating `npm` to the latest version, deleting `node_modules` folder and running again `npm install`?

Comment: yes, that solves perfectly the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this kind of unexpected errors arise without any logic reason at all, it's recommended to follow these steps:

1. Check if you got `npm`'s latest version installed and if you don't upgrade it.
2. Delete your `node_modules` folder.
3. Reinstall all the packages using `npm install`.